# Selection Sort in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I wanted feedback/review on my implementation of a selection sort in c++ (for ints only, no templates). This is my first attempt in c++ making anything beyond simple projects/hello world!

Q: Should my for loops use uniform initialization like `for(int i { 0 }; ...` ?

Q: Should everything else use uniform initialization like I have below?

Q: I read selection is n^2 however I don't loop every field, I loop through only the unsorted portion, is this still n^2 or better?

```
#include <iostream>

void selectionSort(int arr[], int start, int size);
void printArr(int arr[], int size);

int main()
{
  const int size { 11 };
  int arr[size] { 1,9,2,3,4,1,6,6,5,3,8 };
  selectionSort(arr, 0, size);
  return 0;
}

void selectionSort(int arr[], int start, int size)
{
  printArr(arr, size);

  for (int i = start; i < size; i++)
  {
    int min_pos { i };
    for (int x = i; x < size; x++)
    {
      if (arr[x] < arr[min_pos])
      {
        min_pos = x;
      }
    }
    int temp { arr[i] };
    arr[i] = arr[min_pos];
    arr[min_pos] = temp;
    printArr(arr, size);
  }

  printArr(arr, size);
}

void printArr(int arr[], int size)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
1 9 2 3 4 1 6 6 5 3 8
1 9 2 3 4 1 6 6 5 3 8
1 1 2 3 4 9 6 6 5 3 8
1 1 2 3 4 9 6 6 5 3 8
1 1 2 3 4 9 6 6 5 3 8
1 1 2 3 3 9 6 6 5 4 8
1 1 2 3 3 4 6 6 5 9 8
1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 9 8
1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 9 8
1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 9 8
1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 8 9
1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 8 9
1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 8 9
```

Comment: The only "C++" here is `std::cout` and `std::endl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is advisable to use the standard library as much as possible. I'll give you an idea how to implement selection sort using standard functions below. Consider the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void selection_sort(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::iter_swap(it, std::min_element(it, v.end()));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 9, 8, 4, 0, 19, 271, 1 };
    selection_sort(v);

    for (auto elem : v)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
}
```

I would argue the above is actually more readable than what you have wrote, since the functions are well-named and the logic easy to follow. So what the `selection_sort` function does is that it iterates through the vector of integers. It swaps each element with the smallest element in the remaining array, just like we want it to.

Comment: Holy crap... this is amazing. It helps me understand what c++'s really is! C++ is so freaking powerful and Ive neglected to use more than classes!

Comment: @JLivengood I'm glad it was helpful! You can look at [<algorithm>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) for more.

Answer (score 5):

### Style

At the moment, this is C with `iostream`. The style obliterates the point in using C++ at all.

### Code Review

- Almost complete absence of standard library

  The code does not leverage the functionality standard library provides. On top of that, the code is *not better* in any ways than standard library functionality
- Using `int` for size of objects in memory

  Indexable memory is very big nowadays. `int` is guaranteed to be only 16 bits, so it might not be enough to index all of the available memory on the system. Use `std::size_t` for that.
- C style swapping

  C++ has `std::swap()` located in `<utility>`. It will probably be as good as your version, if not better (it might invoke some assembly).
- Using `std::endl`

  `std::endl` does not only put a newline, but also flushes the buffer. Flushing is a very expensive operation, and can hinder performance of the code in tight loops.

### What is done right

- No `using namespace std`

  This is good step forward. Do not use it, in any IDE/text editor code highlighting and completion will be available, if not, find a plugin for your text editor. By grabbing everything in `std`, you will overwhelm the ability of the IDE/text editor to give you real-time code completion suggestions.
- Uniform initialization

  Using uniform initialization avoids all of the vexing parse issues. Do note though, that sometimes they might invoke `std::initializer_list` constructor, which might not be what you need.

### tl;dr

Use Standard library. Use concepts and idioms. Any decent C++ programmer knows that to reimplement standard library one must have a very good reason to do so.